# how to change the columns order 'by default' in PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas

Do you know how to change the columns order 'by default' in this case? I need change this alfabethical order (L M S XL) for other specific order (S M L XL).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows,columns=('COD','COLOUR','SIZE','')).sort_values(by=['COD']
dff = df.groupby(['COD','COLOUR','SIZE']).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()

OUTPUT:
COD  COLOUR  L M S XL
111  black   2 2 3 5
111  white   6 5 8 9
112  green   2 2 6 1

Desired OUTPUT :
COD  COLOUR  S M L XL
111  black   3 2 2 5
111  white   8 5 6 9
112  green   6 2 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a list of columns:

```
order=['COD','COLOUR','S','M','L','XL']
```

Finally use `loc[]` accessor:

```
df=df.loc[:,order]
```

Output of `df`:

```
    COD     COLOUR  S   M   L   XL
0   111     black   3   2   2   5
1   111     white   8   5   6   9
2   112     green   6   2   2   1
```

Comment: Ok, it works. But there are not always 4 sizes. What if there is only M-L-XL ?

Comment: then just create the list of columns by the order in which you wish to want and then pass in `.loc` accessor `df=df.loc[:,order]`

Comment: and how can I create that list of columns?

Comment: like I created in the above example `order=['COD','COLOUR','S','M','L','XL']`

Comment: It works when there are all that elements (S-M-L-XL) but when there are only two 'Sizes' like (COD, COLOUR, M & L) it doesn't work. The following error appears;  """   KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['S', 'XL'], dtype='object')."""

Comment: `order=['COD','COLOUR','M','L']` now try `df=df.loc[:,order]`